# Determine the column type of datagrid

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to customize the header of `DataGrid` by overriding the `AbstractHeaderOrFooterBuilder` abstract class. What I need is to figure out what type is column of each header.

```
Column<T, ?> column = getTable().getColumn(index);
```

Is there a way to find out the type of the wildcard? I'm not talking strictly about java, but java in terms of `GWT`. I know that at runtime there want be any information of the wildcard for me, because of type erasure, but is there a way to determine if the values of the aforementioned column is of type, let's say, `String` or `Date`? I need this information in order to provide a filtering functionality. I need to render different controls for a `Date` filter than those of a `String`.

I've thought about extending the `Column` class in order to store this information but I was curious if there is some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dataStoreName property of Column for this. This won't give you the type directly but you can can e.g. create an enum for the different column types that you have and put that into the property.